# Securing intercom webhooks with signed notifications: what data gets hashed?

Tags: webhooks, intercom

I’m trying to secure my Intercom webhook endpoints and I'm following the instructions outlined here:

- https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#signed-notifications
- https://www.intercom.com/help/apps-in-intercom/apps/webhooks

The problem is, neither of those resources are clear about what data actually gets hashed to create the signature and I’ve tried a bunch of different things and still not getting a match.

Does anyone know what part of the notification request is used to generate the sha1 hash that’s included in that `x-hub-signature` header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend looking through the [intercom-webhooks](https://github.com/intercom-archive/intercom-webhooks) GitHub repo for example code in a variety of programming languages for how to handle the webhook signature.

The signature is computed using the entire payload of the POST request.